Higher chow groups of affine toric varieties
Let $X$ be an affine toric variety defined over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero.
I am trying to use Bloch’s Riemann-Roch Theorem for quasi-projective algebraic schemes in his 1986 paper Algebraic cycles and higher K-theory
$G_n(X)\otimes\mathbb{Q}\cong CH^*(X,n)\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ to compute $G_n(X)\otimes\mathbb{Q}$ for all non-negative integers $n$.
Here $G_n(X)$ is the $n$-th algebraic $G$-theory group of $X$, which comes from the abelian category $M(X)$ of coherent sheaves on $X$.
Are there known results on the higher chow groups of affine toric varieties?
